# Repeat summary for all columns in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, repeat

I have a pandas dataframe that includes over 100 categorical columns, and two numeric columns. For example, in the data below I only included four categorical columns, for simplicity:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Gender': ['M','M','F','M','F','M','F','M','F','F'],
    'Class' : ['A','B','B','C','A','C','B','A','A','C'],
    'Class_2': ['A1','B2','B3','C5','B1','C2','B1','B1','C3','D1'],
    'District' : ['N','N','E','S','S','N','N','E','S','S']
})

df['X1'] = np.random.normal(1000, 55, 10)
df['X2'] = np.random.normal(100, 10, 10)
```

For each categorical column (namely, `Gender`, `Class`, `Class_2`, and `District`) I need to do the following summary:

```
   #Show the distribution of the column, both count and percent
    print((df["Gender"].value_counts(sort=False, normalize=False)))
    print((df["Gender"].value_counts(sort=False, normalize=True))*100)
    
    #Plot the histogram
    plt.figure(figsize=(9, 8))
    plt.hist(df['Gender'], color = 'blue', edgecolor = 'black',
             bins = 30)
    plt.xlabel("Gender")
    plt.ylabel("Count")
    plt.title("Gender distribution")
     

    #Aggregate sum of X1 and X2 by Gender, and find the ratio     
    #ratio by Gender
    var1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Gender')['X2', 'X1'].agg(['sum']).reset_index())
    var1['ratio'] = var1['X2']/var1['X1']
    print(var1)
     
    var1.plot('Gender', 'ratio', kind='bar',
                 colormap='Paired',
                title=' Ratio by Gender')
```

Comment: ok, and what is your question?

Comment: For each categorical column (namely, Gender, Class, Class_2, and District) I need to do the summary I presented in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First parametrize plots / statistics, for example make function or procedure:

```
def plot_stats(column):
   #Show the distribution of the column, both count and percent
    print((df[column].value_counts(sort=False, normalize=False)))
    print((df[column].value_counts(sort=False, normalize=True))*100)
    
    #Plot the histogram
    plt.figure(figsize=(9, 8))
    plt.hist(df[column], color = 'blue', edgecolor = 'black',
             bins = 30)
    plt.xlabel(column)
    plt.ylabel("Count")
    plt.title(f"{column} distribution")
     

    #Aggregate sum of X1 and X2 by Gender, and find the ratio     
    #ratio by Gender
    var1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(column)['X2', 'X1'].agg(['sum']).reset_index())
    var1['ratio'] = var1['X2']/var1['X1']
    print(var1)
     
    var1.plot(column, 'ratio', kind='bar',
                 colormap='Paired',
                title= f' Ratio by {column}')
    #add below line to display each plot after printing output:
    plt.show()
```

Then just run in loop:

```
for col in ['Gender','Class','Class_2','District']:
    plot_stats(col)
```

When working in Jupyter Notebook environment, please note that to display each plot after printing output `plt.show()` is needed as shown in above function `plot_stats`.

Comment: Thanks @ipj, I see that all numeric results for all columns show up first and then the plot, is it possible to keep the order?

Comment: I run this in Spyder so numeric output and plots are separated by default. I guess You are working in Jupyter Notebook environment?

Comment: Yes, I'm working in Jupyter Notebook. Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: I've improved the answer,  it seems to print output and plots in order now.